# Dropdown list trigger jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anybody know the exact reason for this, why drop down is not opening using trigger function. Can anybody Explain this!

$('select').trigger('click');

Thanks.

Comment: All that code does is call the click event handlers for all selects. It has nothing to do with actually opening the drop-downs. That's not possible through JavaScript as far as I know.

Answer (score 2):

You simply can't do this, definitely not cross-browser.  Your *simulating* an event, which isn't the same as the *native* click event, which opens the `<select>`.

This is true in other places as well, the same way a [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) on an `<a>` won't make the browser go to the `href`.